# angularjs expressions displayed instead of Json data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using angularjs, cordova, bootstrap and json.

The problem am facing is on the 1st launch of the application in the search results instead of displaying the Json data it is displaying the angularjs expressions for few seconds and then the expressions are replaced with actual Json values.

Could someone please provide a solution.

```
<table class="responsive table table-bordered table-hover" style="z-index:1">
                    <thead>
                       <tr >
                         <th> </th>
                          <th>Zip</th>
                          <th>City</th>
                          <th>County</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody ng-cloak>

                       <tr ng-repeat-start="r in myData">
                           <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <span ng-if="r.expanded" ng-click="r.expanded = false" style="z-index:1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></span>
                                <span ng-if="!r.expanded" ng-click="r.expanded = true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
                           </td>
                          <td>
                              {{r.zipCode}}

                          </td>
                          <td>
                               {{r.cityNameFull}}  
                          </td>
                          <td>
                                {{r.countyName}}
                          </td>

                       </tr>
                       <tr ng-if="r.expanded"  ng-repeat-end=" ">
                           <th></th>

                                   <td colspan="3" >
                                        <table class="table responsive table-bordered table-hover">

                                            <tr>

                                        <thead>
                                         <th>Jurisdiction</th> 
                                        <th>SalesTax</th>
                                         <th>UseTax</th>

                                        </thead>
                                    </tr> 
                                          <tr ng-if="r.stateSalesTax > 0 || r.stateUseTax > 0">

                                              <td>State</td>

                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.stateSalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.stateUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr> 
                                          <tr ng-if="r.citySalesTax > 0 || r.cityUseTax > 0">
                                              <td>City</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.citySalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.cityUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr>
                                          <tr ng-if="r.countySalesTax > 0 || r.countyUseTax > 0">
                                              <td>County</td>
                                               <td class="two-digits">{{r.countySalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                               <td class="two-digits">{{r.countyUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr ng-if="r.mtaSalesTax > 0 || r.mtaUseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.mtaName}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.mtaSalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.mtaUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                          </tr> 
                                          <tr ng-if="r.spdSalesTax > 0 || r.spdUseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.spdName}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.spdSalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.spdUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr>  
                                          <tr ng-if="r.other1SalesTax > 0 || r.other1UseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.other1Name}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other1SalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other1UseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr> 
                                          <tr ng-if="r.other2SalesTax > 0 || r.other2UseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.other2Name}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other2SalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other2UseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr>  
                                          <tr ng-if="r.other3SalesTax > 0 || r.other3UseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.other3Name}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other3SalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other3UseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr>    
                                          <tr ng-if="r.other4SalesTax > 0 || r.other4UseTax > 0">
                                              <td>{{r.other4Name}}</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other4SalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.other4UseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr> 
                                          <tr class="total" ng-if="r.totalSalesTax >= 0 || r.totalUseTax >= 0">
                                              <td>Total</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.totalSalesTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>
                                              <td class="two-digits">{{r.totalUseTax*100 | number:2}}%</td>

                                          </tr>  
                                        </table>

                                   </td>



                       </tr>
                    </tbody>

                 </table>
```

Comment: Sure, the solution is to fix the code you didn't provide :)

Comment: where is the code .. we are not like Bran .. we can not see everything :)

Comment: @deepak-reddy on first glance i think `ng-cloak` should solve ur issue: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak. However you should provide code

Comment: You could use the Cordova splash screen, and hide it manually when your app is fully rendered.

Comment: @Rahul thank you. i added it but still the issue is not resolved

Comment: @Noman i had posted the code. Bran is busy at winterfel. :)

Comment: @DarthJDG it is not a cordova issue. on the resultpage am facing this issue first it is displaying the static expression and after few seconds it is replacing it with json value

Comment: which specific model is not working  ??  or you can not display any model at all ??

Comment: You said *"on the 1st launch of the application"*, so I assumed the issue is with the initial render, when the DOM is shown before styes and script are loaded. I didn't say there is an issue with Cordova, just that the splash screen is an easy way to cover up initial render issues via manually hiding it from code after everything is properly rendered. This way you don't need to bother with manually setting `display:none` on the whole body for example.

Comment: @Noman it is not regarding model am able to display the json data. but on the 1st launch of the application instead of showing the json data it is 1st displaying the angular code with {{}} and the after 5 secs it is replacing with json data.

Comment: @DarthJDG sry dude. what i was trying to explain is that on first launch of application. if i search for any results. my table is displaying the static angular expressions 1st and then replacing it with the actual json data.

Comment: @Noman please find the image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvhk.jpg

Comment: what do you get if you  print myData in the colsole ??

Comment: it is working fine but in device for few seconds i will see the static angular content and then the data

Comment: @Noman Please watch this video below i have recorded the issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkyLGTV0jLM

Comment: @Rahul https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkyLGTV0jLM please watch this video to view the issue

Comment: It seems u are having ajax call on that particular page controller ? Though ng-cloak should solve ur issue !

Comment: @Rahul thank you bro. ng-clock worked with little customization

Comment: @deepakreddy I shall post this as answer then..please accept to close the thread

Comment: @Rahul i accepted it & thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-cloak` and refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) link for usage of it.